# Maintaining a single instance of a concrete class with unity

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, instantiation

When using unity, if i attempt to inject a concrete type that i havent explicitly registered with the container, unity will attempt to locate the current type and will instantiate a new one for me, before injecting it into the class that depends upon it.

How can i ensure that only a single instance of this type is used? Do i need to explicitly register an instance with the container beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660864%28PandP.20%29.aspx):

> You can use the Unity container to generate instances of any object that has a public constructor (in other words, objects that you can create using the new operator), without registering a mapping for that type with the container. When you call the Resolve method and specify the default instance of a type that is not registered, the container simply calls the constructor for that type and returns the result.

So simply put, **yes**, you have to register a mapping for your type to be able to use it as singleton in your app. You can achieve it using `RegisterInstance` method or `RegisterType` and providing the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` as the lifetime manager.